# What is e.getSource==t?

Tags: java, swing, timer

So in my application I am using the code:

```
if(e.getSource()==btnGo){
    t = new Timer(1000, this);
    showMessage();
    t.start();
}

if(e.getSource()==t){
    clearMessage();
    t.stop();
}
```

It displays a message for a second before removing it, I would just like to know what event is being triggered at     `(e.getSource==t)`

EDIT - added brackets.

Comment: That's not actual Java code. `clearMessage;` is probably a method invocation, right? So it should have `()` etc.

Comment: It is self-explanatory: `e.getSource()` returns the `Timer t` if the event triggered by it - so if you started the Timer before in the `if`-statement above

Comment: @aioobe and `showMessage` should also have a `()` behind it

Comment: @msrd0, yes, and getSource as well.

Comment: @aioobe Oh yes, I just overread it because I normally see `e.getSource()` where `e` is any Event

Comment: @aioobe This is not the actual code I'm using, I replaced the actual method call with showMessage() and clearMessage().
and msrd0 i don't understand your first comment, is it finished?

Comment: @msrd0 I like how you decide to point out that I had brackets missing, when you obviously knew what I meant instead of providing ANY help whatsoever.

Comment: _"So in my application I am using the code:"_ - Why are you using it if you don't know what it does?

Comment: @peeskillet, I was given it without being told exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I assume "e" is the event that you are currently handling.

Your code checks which object fired the event and reacts accordingly. If the event was fired by btnGo, it will create the Message and create a new Timer t which it also starts. The Timer will fire an event after the specified time. So, after 1 second passed, the method will be called again, with a different event e. This time, it's source is the timer, thus clearing the Message as specified in the second block.